# Auto Layout crash on iOS 10.0.2

Tags: ios, swift

Terminating app due to uncaught exception:

> 'NSGenericException', reason: 'Unable to install constraint on view'

Does the constraint reference something from outside the subtree of the view?  That's illegal.

Was working fine on iOS 9 and 10.0.1

Comment: Please, post some code.

Comment: really? 10.0.2 not work?

Comment: Does it affect a layout loaded from a XIB/NIB file or a layout constrcuted with Objective-C or Swing code? If it's the latter one, show the code.

Comment: Well I am just dismissing a controller nothing wrong with layout

Comment: We have to deliver the app to client by this Friday, did any body get any solution for this